# Document AI v1Beta3 API coordinate mapping to pdf coordinates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I parsed a PDF file using [API version v1beta3](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest) and got the coordinates of a table as seen below.

```
     "normalizedVertices": [
              {
                "x": 0.6894705,
                "y": 0.016400337
              },
              {
                "x": 0.87983346,
                "y": 0.016400337
              },
              {
                "x": 0.87983346,
                "y": 0.026072329
              },
              {
                "x": 0.6894705,
                "y": 0.026072329
              }
            ]
```

How to convert these to PDF coordinates ?

Comment: The values on the output should be applicable for PDF. As per definition of the [Normalized Vertex](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/Document#normalizedvertex) - "A vertex represents a 2D point in the image. NOTE: the normalized vertex coordinates are relative to the original image and range from 0 to 1.". Also what will you do with these vertices?

Comment: I had used v1API to get the coordinates of tables in an image. There the calculated vertices were fallling at the right place.    
Here in v1beta3 the input is pdf file. The calculated vertices are not falling at the right place. I am referring the coordinate system present in https://online.sodapdf.com/  
The calculated vertices along with the pdf file will be given as input to a python program which fetches table data and exports them in excel.

Answer (score 3):

I tested a pdf form (gs://cloud-samples-data/documentai/loan_form.pdf) and is from [Document AI docs](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/quickstart-console). I used both v1 and v1beta3, got same results and it works as expected.

The **x and y values returned** by `normalizedVertices` are from 0 to 1. Document AI calculates the values of x and y with respect to the point of origin which is the top left corner of the image. The bounding box logic is explained in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/csv-format). While online.sodapdf.com calculates value of x with respect to the origin, value of y with respect to the maximum point.

To convert the values to actual x and y coordinates just like in **online.sodapdf.com** see convertion:

```
x = x * width 
y = height - (y * height))
```

To test this, the sample document has a width = 612 and height = 792 and selected an object to convert coordinates.

The returned object at loan_form.pdf have the coordinates presented under "NormalizedVertex" column. Using the formula above, you will get the converted coordinates. The calculated value may have minimal difference versus the actual, this is maybe due to the object detection algorithm of both tools. See testing done below:

[image]

---

**Width and height of the tested document:**

[image]

**Test object detected loan_form.pdf:**

[image]

**Tested object detected in online.sodapdf.com:**

[image]

Comment: @Pankaj S Y Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Yes, it helped me. Thanks for such a nicely written answer!!

I have upvoted it but don't have the reputation, so won't be shown here.